# Using resources depending on configuration in android app

Tags: android, android-resources, android-productflavors

I am developing android application that is targeted to different clients. 
Currently I have organized everything with build flavors so every client can get his own application. I have some graphic resources as well as some flavor specified Strings (as build config field) and everything is working great.
However... as number of clients is still increasing... I wouldn't want to have app specific for every client. I would prefer having only one app and configure it on runtime.
I wonder if there is some pattern how to organize it. Graphic resources aren't so big I can easly handle to load all of them to one app. I could also imagine changing buildconfigfields to some common resource. But... I still don't know if it is good way? What do you think?

Comment: Hello
You can do a builder for your app. Via the builder, you will have the possibility to create different apps. Also, you will have only one codebase

Comment: I have currently one codebase and possibility to create different app (using product flavors) but I would prefer to build only one app and configure it on runtime

Comment: You can update your package name in runtime

Answer (score 0):

We have done the same thing, using Flavours; and it works great!

What you have to do is create a `res` folder for each flavour. So you have a structure that looks something like:

```
|--> app
|----> src
|------> main (this is where you 'base' product build goes

|------> flav1 (this is named the same as one of your flavours)
|--------> google-services.json (google services for flav1)
|--------> res (res files for flav1)
|----------> drawable-xxxhdpi (drawables for flav1)
|----------> values (values files for flav1, e.g. strings.xml)

|------> flav2 (this is named the same as one of your flavours) 
|--------> google-services.json (google services for flav2)
|--------> res (res files for flav2)
|----------> drawable-xxxhdpi (drawables for flav2)
|----------> values (values files for flav2, e.g. strings.xml)
```

app build.gradle

```
...
productFlavors {
    flav1 {
        applicationId = "com.your.appl.flav1";
        versionNameSuffix "_FLAV_1"
    }
    flav2 {
        applicationId = "com.your.appl.flav2";
        versionNameSuffix "_FLAV_2"
    }
}
...
```

You resources are taken from the flavour folder first and then from main. Hope this helps!!

Comment: This is exactly what I have now. This is working great but it requires to have separate apk for every client. My goal is to have one universal apk and configure it at runtime

Comment: Wouldn't that bloat the APK making it larger to download? Unless you had some form of configuration setting that then (as part of the set-up) went off to a server to get the artifacts. We use Bitbucket Pipelines configured to use a docker container that has Android Studio installed, and it does a pretty good job of churning out our APK's.

Comment: @user3921796 Some application configs can't change at runtime, such as applicationId, app name and so on, so build flavor is necessary. If you want to configure others at runtime, maybe java interface and static factory method will help you. BTW, build flavors also support java/kotlin source code just like resources.

Comment: @GavinHarris In my specific situation all resources for all current clients weight about 2MB - there are xml configuration files and simple drawables (currently kept under flavor directory)

Comment: OKay, the only possible downsides I can see then would be:
1. New user process - I'm guessing that a new user would need to pick a configuration / enter a client number when signing in (which can then be used to switch up the resources).
2. New clients - you'd roll out an updated application for any new clients, which would trigger all existing clients downloading the update. Again this is not huge and could be beneficial as all clients would be on the exact same version of code.